# Keep JQuery dialog open on mouse hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show notification on master page and for that I am using JQuery dialog.
I could achieve Auto show and hide on page load using below code. But I want to keep dialog open if it is hovered by Mouse.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 100,
        hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 2000
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        close: function(){
            // $(this).dialog('destroy');
        },
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 2000
        }
    });

    var x = $("#<%= imgNotifcation.ClientID %>").position().left + $("#<%= imgNotifcation.ClientID %>").outerWidth();
    var y = $("#<%= imgNotifcation.ClientID %>").position().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();

    // var x = 0;

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    $('#dialog').dialog( 'option', 'position', [x-90, y+25] ); 

});
```

This work fine but it hides a dialog even if I hover div #dialog.
I want to keep dialog open if it hovers.

Comment: I can't see any code here that is triggering a close when you hover the dialog. Are you sure the entirety of your code is here?

Comment: @Danny H .. Yes entire code is here. Dialog close event is written in Open event itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You immediately call the close function after the dialog is shown. You can not stop that this way. What you can do is set the close on a timer, stop the timer on hover and restart is, when the mouse leaves the dialog.

You need a variable to store the close timer:

```
var dialogCloseTimer = null;
```

In the dialog configuration, start the close timer with 1 second (1000 ms):

```
open: function ()  {
    var self = this;
    dialogCloseTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).dialog('close');
    }, 1000);
},
```

After the dialog is configured, set listeners for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to stop and restart the close timer:

```
$("#dialog").on("mouseenter", function() {
    window.clearTimeout(dialogCloseTimer);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var self = this;
    dialogCloseTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).dialog('close');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.. Great Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example

```js
var i = 0;
$(".overout")
  .mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse over x " + i);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
  });

var n = 0;
$(".enterleave")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    n += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse enter x " + n);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse leave");
  });
```

```css
.out {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: #d6edfc;
  float: left;
}

.in {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #fc0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="out overout">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="out enterleave">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

And now when your mouse will be on that div just do your dialog